# RPC call from NodeJs to Erlang Application

Tags: node.js, erlang, rpc, gen-server

I have an application which is written in Erlang and the functions are exported along with its modules. Currently im having a YAWS web server which is the webserver for erlang. so calling an RPC is basically a gen server call where i get the a pid by passing the process group name and calling the module name, function name and and its arguments.

I am trying to migrate from YAWS to NodeJS as the webserver for all the front end applications and im stuck with a solution to call the RPCs from the NodeJs.

If anyone came across any solutions please do let me know.

Comment: It's not clear how you call things in your Erlang app from outside the process.  Is it done via the YAWS web server so each call is an http request?  Or some other way?

Comment: Its currently called inside the yaws web app using a gen server call. I want to migrate from yaws to node js and call the rpc from nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to call erlang code from NodeJS is to use a webserver be it Yaws or Cowboy (which is seeing more use these days). There is not a direct way to call an erlang function from NodeJS as far as I know.